# Como obter o número de linhas afetadas por um Insert em uma procedure com PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma procedure que executa um `INSERT`. Ao aciona-la por meio do `PDO::execute()` e tentar obter o número de linhas afetadas o que me é retornado é o número de linhas executadas pela procedure, contrariamente ao número de registros inseridos.

Procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procCrtEmpresa`(IN `prmNomEmp` TEXT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE iProxChave INT Default 0;
   SELECT 1 into iProxChave;
   SELECT IF(MAX(COD_EMP) IS NULL, 0, MAX(COD_EMP))+1 INTO iProxChave FROM empresa;
   INSERT INTO empresa values (iProxChave,  prmNomEmp);
END$$
```

PHP

```php
//abro a conexão
self::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $dbhost .  ";dbname=" . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$stmt = self::$conn->prepare("CALL procCrtEmpresa(?,?)");

$stmt->bindValue(1, "Empresa ", PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Valor de `$result` é 3

O valor de `$result` corresponde as 3 execuções de `Select` e `Insert` dentro da procedure (linhas 4, 5 e 6), quando deveria ser 1, pois foi realizada uma inserção no banco de dados.

Como faço para obter o valor real de linhas afetadas?
Obs: existem procedures com processamentos diversos antes de realizar o Insert e por isso inseri as linhas 4 e 5 na procedure em questão para simular. Ademais, há exigência de ser realizado pelo PDO e não no formato procedural do PHP.

Comment: Eu achei a pergunta boa, não tenho ainda uma resposta dentro do PHP mas gostaria de deixar uma contribuição: Na documentação [PDOStatement::rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) diz que `rowCount()` retorna somente o número de linhas afetadas pelas instrução `DELETE`, `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` ou seja para qualquer outra declaração(no caso chama de uma STORED PROCEDURE) o comportamento do método é indefinido. Mesmo se não chegarem a uma solução dentro do PHP ainda é possível fazer com que essa contagem seja retornada pelo próprio procedimento usando DDL/DQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei um caminho que funciona e creio ser útil evidenciar uma rumo que não deu certo.

Primeiro (não deu certo): não mais utilizei o `$stmt->rowCount()`. Então, criei um parâmetro de saída na `procedure` tentei enviar um parâmetro como `OUT` para a procedure (`bindParam`), de modo a obter seu retorno após execução, conforme Documentação do `PDO` PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php). A solução não funcionou, pois não consegui recuperar o parâmetro de retorno (na `procedure` este foi adicionado como `OUT` e `INOUT` e mesmo assim não deu certo com o `bindParam`).

Adiante (funciona): a solução foi manter o parâmetro de saída na procedure (pode ser `OUT` ou `INOUT`), mas não enviar conforme a documentação do PHP (`bindParam`), mas sim como uma variável do SQL. O parâmetro de entrada necessário foi enviado como `bindValue` (`bindParam` envia como referência, o que não é o caso deste parâmetro), conforme abaixo:

Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procCrtEmpresa`(IN `prmNomEmp` TEXT, OUT `prmQtdRegAft` INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE iProxChave INT Default 0;
   SELECT 1 into iProxChave;
   SELECT IF(MAX(COD_EMP) IS NULL, 0, MAX(COD_EMP))+1 INTO iProxChave FROM empresa;
   INSERT INTO empresa values (iProxChave,  prmNomEmp);

   SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO prmQtdRegAft;
END$$
```

Foi adicionado o parâmetro de saída (`OUT`) `prmQtdRegAft` e a este foi inserido o número de linhas afetadas, conforme instrução `SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO prmQtdRegAft;` após `Insert`. Esta instrução pega o número de linhas afetadas pela última instrução executada na `procedure`, no caso o `Insert`.

PHP

```
//abro a conexão
self::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $dbhost .  ";dbname=" . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$stmt = self::$conn->prepare("CALL procCrtEmpresa(?,@QtdRegAfc)");

$stmt->bindValue(1, "Empresa ", PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

$result = self::$conn->query("SELECT @QtdRegAfc")->fetch()[0];
```

Valor de $result é 1.

Observe que na preparação da chamada foi passado o parâmetro nomeado `@QtdRegAfc` e, após a execução, é realizado um `Select` nesse, obtendo o valor do mesmo na posição `[0]`.